# Treatment for pain in fingers after workout

Tags: weightlifting, pain, grip-strength

I just began weightlifting three times a week. The workout consists things like deadlifts, squats, barbell rows, dumbell bench presses, etc...

I've been feeling pain in my fingers afterwards and they've felt a bit stiff. I know that my grip strength has always been pretty low.

Should I be taking time off to let my fingers rest or should I treat it with something like ice?

Comment: Maybe read up on this one: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/26089/pinky-finger-movement-affected-by-lifting-weights/26091#26091

Comment: My finger's don't get stuck. There's just a noticeable slight pain in them whenever I move them. Particularly in my index and middle fingers.

Comment: also related (meta): http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/q/625/7091

Comment: Since you just began, you probably just haven't adapted to it yet. I'd say that if it doesn't go away in another couple of weeks, you should see a medical professional. Static holds might also help (farmer carries, holding deadlifts at the top for as long as you can, etc). Wrapping your fingers in athletic tape might help, but that can get spendy if your fingers never adjust on their own.

Comment: You should see a physical therapist to get it assessed first. It’s difficult for people here to give any advice if we can’t see and conduct tests, if we are even qualified

Answer (score 0):

It is normal mild numbness you get on your fingers.

The tendons moving the fingers are really exposed and holding heavy weights in your hands can numb your fingers by compressing the tendon against the bone.

After some times you will get used to it,also developing calluses helps.